# Must I call -deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: inside an -beginUpdates -endUpdates block?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Must I call -deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: inside an -beginUpdates -endUpdates block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you should as it avoids the table being repainted while you modify it. If you only delete a single row it's a tad overkill.

Comment: so if I delete a single row I should not put it in an update block? or should I?

Comment: No, you can but you don't need to. It is advised to do it when updating multiple rows. For a single row you're fine without the update block.